# C# - HackerRank simpleArraySum

Tags: c#

Now, I may get negative points because perhaps somewhere in vast internet there is already an answer to this but I tried to look for it and I simply couldnt find it.

The gist of the problem is that HackerRanks wants you to create an array with a size decided by the user, then have the user add its values (integers) and finally have the program sum its values.

There are plenty of ways to do it and I already know how to but my problem is that I just can't understand Hackerrank's code sample in C# it gave me. I commented the parts I don't understand, which is most of it:

```
    static int simpleArraySum(int n, int[] ar) {
    // Complete this function
    int sum = 0;
    foreach( var item in ar){
        sum += item;
    }
    return sum;
}

static void Main(String[] args) {
    //I know what this does
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    //I am lost here, just why create a string array and add the split method?
    string[] ar_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    //I dont understand here neither, what is it converting? What is the parse for?
    int[] ar = Array.ConvertAll(ar_temp,Int32.Parse);
    //Why send the n when all you need is the array itself?
    int result = simpleArraySum(n, ar);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

I know some people hate HackerRank, and honestly, I do too but it does gives me some nice ways to test my limited skills in coding with c# and testing my logic. So, if there are better sites that helps you test your logic as a CS please share them with me.

---

Here is the code I made to solve this problem in Visual Studio but for some stupid reason Hackerrank wont accept it unless I make custom inputs:

```
    //This code can be potentially shorter using the code commented further below.
    //For practice's sake, it was made longer.
    static int simpleArraySum(int[] arr_temp)
    {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (var item in arr_temp)
        {
            total += item;              
        }
        return total;
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr_temp = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr_temp[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        int result = simpleArraySum(arr_temp);
        //int result = arr_temp.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: `Split` takes the input like "1 2 3" and creates an array of string values split on the space.  The next line converts each value in the array to an int with the parse method.  As for passing `n`, you're right that it isn't necessary, really it's a hold over from other languages like C where arrays don't have a length property.

Comment: Juharr, but is it really necessary to make an string[] array?

Comment: No you could just do `int[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();` if you use Linq.  If you don't use Linq then yeah you'd need the intermediate string array.

Comment: Hm, check the code I made to solve the problem in VisualStudio, I added it. I can still sum the array using `int result = arr_temp.Sum()` which I assume is LINQ without using an intermediate string array. Can you explain me why would I need an intermediate?

Comment: I like this approach: `int result = Enumerable.Range(0, Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())).Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())).Sum();`.

Comment: Why is it even needed to make a string array and then turn it into a int array? Is it good practice?

Comment: Enigmativity, can you please explain how does your approach works? I am a beginner in c#

Comment: @Eduardo - Sorry, it's LINQ. You probably should stick with the basics for now, but LINQ will make your life much easier when you're ready to learn it.

Comment: I see, thank you then. I better not bite more than what I can chew.

Comment: @Enigmativity That's great except that the input is how many numbers on the first line and then the numbers to sum space separated on the next line.  You cannot change how the input is given to you on HackerRank

Comment: @Eduardo You're new solution is reading one number per line.  The point of the other code is that the numbers to be summed will be on one line space separated.  So, yes if you change how the numbers are insert then yeah, you don't need the intermediate string array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert to string array since if you're on the main method, all it gets are string values from the argument list. To get the sum then you need to convert the string into a usable number / integer.

I agree that it doesn't make sense to send the first argument `n` in `simpleArraySum` because `n` is simply unused.

as for the part `int[] ar = Array.ConvertAll(ar_temp,Int32.Parse);` it simply tries to take in all the integers into the array. It is also risky because if you accidentally pass in a string then it will throw an error i.e. pass in "3 4 1 f" <- f will throw an exception, unless this is the desired behaviour.

Personally I think the main method should not be interested in getting involved too much with the data, the heavy lifting should be done in the methods. The better version perhaps would be to modify `simpleArraySum` and refactor that line in like:

```
static int simpleArraySum(string input)
    {
        String[] fields = input.Split(null);
        List<int> vals = new List<int>();
        foreach (string i in fields)
        {
            var j = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(i, out j)) vals.Add(j);

        }

        int sum = 0;
        foreach (var item in vals)
        {
            sum += item;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

I introduced the use of generic list because it's more readable if not cleaner, although the use of List might look overkill to some programmers and might not be as light weight as just using an array, hence on the other hand you can easily stick to using arrays except that it needs to be initialized with the length i.e. `int[] vals = new int[fields.Length];` Roughly:

```
static int simpleArraySum(string input)
    {
        String[] fields = input.Split(null);

        int[] vals = new int[fields.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
        {
            var j = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(fields[i], out j)) vals[i] = j;

        }

        int sum = 0;
        foreach (var item in vals)
        {
            sum += item;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: I understand most of what you are doing except why add a `var j = 0` and use it in  `if (Int32.TryParse(i, out j)) vals.Add(j);` I like the way you did it tho. And why is it necessary to make a string array first? Why don't make a int array from the beginning or a list array for that matter?

Comment: Int32.TryParse needs an object or variable to put the resulting output into before you can assign the result. The reason I use Int32.TryParse is that it will not stop the program and throw an exception, what it will do is simply try to convert all the strings are qualified as integers. That is why:

`var j = 0; //currently value is zero`

`// if for example you sent this string value: 32 then:

Int32.TryParse("32", out j); // if the string "32" is an integer then j ill be assigned the value 32`

After which you can use j (with its new value) to what ever purpose you need it for

Comment: [Why don't make a int array from the beginning or a list array for that matter?]

Because assuming you're using this app form the console (because it has a main method), all it can receive are text/string values. That is why you need to handle first the string, because all values from the console come in as strings not integers

Comment: Oh, I feel silly now. Is true, console values are strings. But what if you do this:      `array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine))` ? you can convert values immediately to int, right?

Comment: No that will not work because of 3 reasons:

(1) Convert.Int32 will not return an array of integers, it will simply return 1 integer. 

(2) Console.ReadLine will also not return an array of strings.

(3) You need to split the string input to produce an array of string

Comment: I understand, but what if you use a for? (I am sorry if I am being so insistent) `for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++){ array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine)) }`.

Comment: Readline reads the entire thing it received in one line. if for example while running your app on the command line and you wrote in one line:

`"Dogs 5 Cats 3 in box"` then imagine you need the total combined dogs and cats... if you just use Console.Readline then you will never be able to extract 5 and 3 from the string, and the result will be: `Convert.ToInt32("Dogs 5 Cats 3 in box")` this will cause an error/unexpected behaviour. The reason for Split(null) is because you need to put each word in separate array cells for processing [0]: Dogs,  [1]: 5, [2] Cats, [3]: 3, [4]: in, [5]: box

Comment: I see! Thanks, I understand now.

Comment: Glad to help! :-)

Comment: You do not pass `null` to `Split`, just calling `input.Split()` will do the same thing.

Comment: @juharr - Thanks .Split() is fine as well, I'm just used to making the arguments parameterized  say .Split(params)  and var is declared in an upper part of the code/class which makes the code more maintainable by avoiding magic values :-)

Answer (score 0):

here my code i hope that helps

```
static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar,int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10000)
            {
                if (count == ar.Length)
                {
                    if (!ar.Any(item => (item < 0 || item >= 10000)))
                    {
                        return ar.Sum();
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;        
    }
```

and in main

```
            int arCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), arTemp => Convert.ToInt32(arTemp));
            int result = simpleArraySum(arr, arCount);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

since **`Array.ConvertAll()`** takes a string and convert it to one type array
int or float for example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Whilst your code may solve the problem, the original question was to understand what certain parts of the original code did. Could update your answer to explain why your code works and what is different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

For users still looking for a 100% C# solution: In above mentioned coding websites do not modify the main function. The aim of the test is to complete the function via the online complier.

```cs
 using System.Linq;
 public static int simpleArraySum(List<int> ar)
    {
     int sum = ar.Sum();
     return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?